# Can Doxygen show what variables are used to calculate one variable in an assignment statement

Tags: doxygen

I would like to have in the documentation hyperlinks for each variable that show all the operations in which a value was assigned to such variable.
I have tried `!@` and `!>` after the assignment operation but I only get a description under the variable. I also tried `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES` and `REFERENCES_RELATION = YES` but works for routine calls.

This is an example but it can be in the main or in a subroutine.

```
subroutine intrestbuild(Mat,aggr,Restrict)
      implicit none
      Type(SpMtx), intent(in) :: Mat !< our fine level matrix
      Type(Aggrs), intent(in) :: aggr
      Type(SpMtx), intent(out) :: Restrict !< Our restriction matrix

      Mat = aggr * Restrict

    end subroutine
```

So clicking Mat in the documentation would show me `aggr * Restrict`, which would be both applicable hyperlinks, so I can go down the rabbit hole. Is this possible?

Comment: What would happen when `Mat` is calculated on more than one place? No doxygen has no such facilities unless you place it explicitly in the (brief) documentation of the variable (e.g. by means of a `\snippet`). In the later case it might show as a tooltip in the HTML documentation.

Comment: @albert it can simply show multiple lines where the variable is used. I am surprised it doesn't do that, seem relatively easy to parse code using '=' to mark assignment operations. Can you elaborate how \snippet works?

Comment: Regarding the `\snippet` see the doxygen documentation. Regarding the "seem relatively easy to parse code using '=' to mark assignment operations". The shown example is quite simple, but  how about a cascade of calls ? what would you want to see at the place of e.g. the call of interestBuild? But as it "seem relatively easy to parse code using '=' to mark assignment operations" please have a go at it for the languages (input and output supported buy doxygen) but I cannot guarantee that it wil make a release though.

Comment: @albert I mean for someone who has written all that sacred code that generates Doxygen documentation, it should a breeze :). It doesn't have to be a full blown implementation at first.